# Shut down time is too long for around ten minutes

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have recently installed ubuntu with the recommendation of one my friends. Is is cool and work great. But unfortunately the shut down time is around 10 to 15 minutes which is quite very unexpected with ubuntu kind of operating systems since they are very light. I don't play much videos and use my PC for a very less. Right now I'm using a dual boot with windows but there is no problem with the windows OS. My laptop is not overheating as I have checked the temperature and it is 53*F. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Open your Terminal window and enter the below command.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/init/network-manager.conf
```

Once the configuration file is opened, copy and paste the below code, below the existing ‘stop on stopping dbus’.

```
kill timeout 1
```

**Step 2:**
       I do not think the below step is necessary, but you can do the same to the ‘modem-manager’, just in case. For that, enter the below command.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/init/modemmanager.conf
```

Then look for the existing ‘stop on stopped network-manage’ text line, and simply paste the below code just below it.

```
kill timeout 1
```

**Update:**

```
sudo apt-get autoremove modemmanager

sudo rm /etc/init/modemmanager.conf

sudo apt-get install modemmanager
```

cheers.................